# Angular 2 - what is lodash and is it mandatory to use it in typescript application?

Tags: performance, angular, typescript, lodash

I am making Angular 2 application in typescript and I am not sure about lodash package, that whether to use it or is it compulsory for typescript for performance improvements ?
should I use **"@types/lodash"** , if lodash is required for typescript functionality and performance improvements ?

Comment: I think you mean https://lodash.com/ and no typescript doesnt need lodash..https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/lodash

Answer (score 3):

Lodash is Underscore inspired utility library and you don't have to use it neither for Typescript nor for Angular2, unless you need it.